# Detect keypress event after enter has been hit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a search functionality where if the the user types in, an autosuggestion box appears. As soon as he hits enter, the autosuggestion box disappears, the search results get appended and the cursor in the search bar disappears. Now when the user again focuses on the search(to type again), the autosuggestion box appears again.

I am unable to achieve the latter part of the statement.

In the below code, consider "child-div" as the autosuggestion box.

So far, I am able to achieve -

1. As soon as the user enters three letters, the box appears.
2. On hitting enter, it disappears.

What I want to achieve further -

1. After the second step above, the "I" cursor should disappear from the search box.
2. On focusing on the search box again, the auto-box should appear again.

```
<div class="container">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded rounded-pill" placeholder="Text input" id="searchbar">
              <div class="child-div" style="background-color: blueviolet; width: 50%; height: 200px; display: none;">
                CHILD DIV
              </div>
            </div>
```

```
$('#searchbar').on('input keydown', function (e) {

    if ($('#searchbar').val().length >= 3) {
        $('.child-div').show();
    }

    if( e.which == 13){
        $('.child-div').hide();
    }

})
```

How to achieve the last scenario? Can anyone please help?

Thankss !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it would be as follows

```js
$('#searchbar').on('input keydown', function (e) {
    if ($('#searchbar').val().length >= 3) {
        $('.child-div').show();
    }

    if( e.which == 13){
        $('.child-div').hide();
        e.target.blur();
    }
})

$('#searchbar').on('focus', function (e) {
    if ($('#searchbar').val().length >= 3) {
        $('.child-div').show();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded rounded-pill" placeholder="Text input" id="searchbar">
              <div class="child-div" style="background-color: blueviolet; width: 50%; height: 200px; display: none;">
                CHILD DIV
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here you just perform a blur event after hitting enter and also register focus event, which checks if it should open the child div or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery blur() and focus() event. When the user press enter, we will programmatically close the box and trigger input blur() event to unfocus it. Then register a focus() event that show the box whenever the input is focus.

- https://api.jquery.com/blur/
- https://api.jquery.com/focus/